# Projection query with MongDb using Expression is not working with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, asp.net-core, mongodb-query

I'm working on application that uses `MongoDb` as the database and `.Net Core 3.0` as the framework. To fetch the data from the database, I have created a `DbContext` class and using the 'Projection' feature of `MongoDb`. I'm not able to pass the appropriate projection. Following is the code for
`DbContext.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace Test.DbContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Standard CRUD Operations with MongoDb  
    /// </summary>
    public class MongoDbContext   
    {
        #region Properties
        private readonly IMongoClient _mongoDbClient = null;

        private readonly IMongoDatabase _mongoDb = null;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public MongoDbContext(IOptions<MongoSetting> mongoConfigs)
        {
            _mongoDbClient = new MongoClient(mongoConfigs.Value.ConnectionString);
            _mongoDb = _mongoDbClient.GetDatabase(mongoConfigs.Value.DatabaseName);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Read Collection (Fetch all the fields from the document)
        public TDocument GetOne<TDocument>(string collectionName, Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filter)
        {
            IMongoCollection<TDocument> mongoCollection = _mongoDb.GetCollection<TDocument>(collectionName);
            return mongoCollection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Project Collection (Fetch the specific fields from the document)
        public TProjection ProjectOne<TDocument, TProjection>(string collectionName,
        Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filter,
        Expression<Func<TDocument, TProjection>> projection)
        {
            IMongoCollection<TDocument> mongoCollection = _mongoDb.GetCollection<TDocument>(collectionName);
            return mongoCollection.Find(filter).Project(projection).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

To call the function `ProjectOne()`, I have to pass the filter and projection but I'm not able to build the appropriate expression. Following are the data model and calling function:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace Test 
{
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class Employee   
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonElement("_id")]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("type")]
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("id")]
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("name")]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm calling the dbContext in Customer Repository as:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace Test.Repositories
{
    public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
    {
        #region Properties
        private readonly IMongoDbContext _dbContext = null;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public CustomerRepository(IMongoDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        public EmployeeCollection GetSpecificData()
        {
            Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> filter = x => x.CustomerId == "1002";
            ProjectionDefinition<Employee> projection = Builders<Employee>.Projection.Exclude(x=> x.Id);

            // Giving exception
            //Cannot implicitly convert type 'MongoDB.Driver.ProjectionDefinition<Employee>' to 
            //'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Employee, Employee>>
            var result = _dbContext.ProjectOne<Employee, Employee>("employee", filter, projection);

        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

How to pass the projection in proper way?

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested the following but i think you can fix the exception changing the method signature of `ProjectOne` like so:

```cs
        public TProjection ProjectOne<TDocument, TProjection>(
            string collectionName,
            Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filter,
            ProjectionDefinition<TProjection> projection
            )
```

if you want to keep `Expression<Func<TDocument, TProjection>> projection` then you need to change how you build the projection like so:

```cs
       Expression<Func<Employee, Employee>> projection = 
           x => new Employee { CustomerName = x.CustomerName, CustomerId = x.CustomerId, Type = x.Type };
```

the downside of that is you can't just exclude a single property like with the builder.